# Load Matrices From File - Python

Tags: python, file, matrix

I have a problem with loading the matrix from a text file to Python. I have a txt file with matrices that looks like this:

```
Matrix # 1[6 x 8]
[[0.0322202  0.09434484 0.25002295 0.2528428  0.10415784 0.24142196
0.010517   0.25487851]
[0.18335361 0.1277445  0.06118253 0.18690019 0.20396079 0.28628478
0.23368012 0.07932863]
[0.01586491 0.08351546 0.09179019 0.19086502 0.26448857 0.00341661
0.0076354  0.14970549]
[0.05323177 0.01803223 0.26651485 0.249316   0.00885857 0.28183164
0.06242965 0.10416661]
[0.05393575 0.2685312  0.0928845  0.0165103  0.19793575 0.18197242
0.10990779 0.11711208]
[0.11764279 0.23854231 0.14737164 0.15334971 0.26638431 0.04492217 
0.12121334 0.0157779 ]]
-------------------------
Matrix # 2[8 x 8]
[[0.03673123 0.04280058 0.13064546 0.0483846  0.06306662 0.04791767
0.20136789 0.06709436]
[0.00859638 0.2915551  0.1329647  0.00975984 0.12029034 0.2637118
0.12587069 0.11391991]
[0.05633049 0.08800232 0.03203959 0.02466364 0.10011332 0.15201659
0.22264326 0.0558971 ]
[0.05053821 0.04099701 0.27159803 0.08778437 0.20792823 0.2030534
0.25036928 0.16582882]
[0.16867485 0.03230341 0.19495864 0.10821256 0.12185273 0.05480103
0.22728856 0.25456569]
[0.02218817 0.23359441 0.15457978 0.0275037  0.06745245 0.12328887
0.16972525 0.02161821]
[0.28029231 0.16327778 0.27735648 0.20591421 0.21236012 0.17597595
0.20992926 0.01747133]
[0.10150612 0.22284606 0.11146442 0.18066627 0.12760146 0.10264632
0.24329665 0.26529221]]
-------------------------
Matrix # 3[8 x 5]
[[0.0044761  0.26838514 0.22510378 0.22843132 0.07689473]
[0.16908802 0.15970796 0.25875775 0.04569838 0.04147033]
[0.08524995 0.04703752 0.05619528 0.14943606 0.24411115]
[0.0667661  0.13352421 0.19563742 0.11554089 0.10493734]
[0.14797975 0.06908592 0.06823431 0.04430664 0.09185596]
[0.02574791 0.0367757  0.23516482 0.1551992  0.27722899]
[0.14542998 0.01641985 0.24688273 0.21755754 0.09459343]
[0.26374249 0.12827675 0.1170908  0.004356   0.08593468]]
-------------------------
```

and a thousand similar matrices.

I wrote a Python code that looks like this:

```
import csv

matrices = []

if __name__ == "__main__":

with open('matrices-2-2.txt', 'r') as file:
    matrix_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter =" ")
    current_matrix = [];

    for row in matrix_reader:
        if row == "-------------------------":
            matrices.append(current_matrix)
            current_matrix = []
        elif row == "Matrix":
            self()
        else:
            current_matrix.append(list(map(float, row)))

print(matrices)
```

I managed to load the matrices. At the moment, unfortunately, I have a problem when trying to multiply them. I created the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import time
import numpy
import re


def matrix_multiplication(list1, list2):
    A = numpy.matrix(list1)
    B = numpy.matrix(list2)
    return A * B


def counting(dane):
    left_matrix = matrices[0]

    for matrix in matrices[1:]:
        left_matrix = numpy.matrix(left_matrix)
        matrix = numpy.matrix(matrix)
        left_matrix = matrix_multiplication(left_matrix, matrix)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    matrices = []
    start = time()
    with open('matrices-2-2.txt', 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
        # gets each matrix based on the pattern [[ ]]
    matrices_string = re.findall("\[([\d\s.\n\]\[]+)\]", content)
    # loops over each matrix
    for matrix_string in matrices_string:
        # parses each row of the matrix
        matrix_rows = re.findall("\[([\d\s.\n\]]+)\]", matrix_string)
        # gets all the numbers for each row of the matrix and remakes   the matrix as a list of floats
        matrices.append([list(map(float, re.findall("\d+\.\d+", row))) for row in matrix_rows])

    print('Load Matrices')
    np = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print('You have', np, 'processors')
    counting(matrices)
    stop = time()

    print('The Calculation took ', stop - start, 'seconds')

    matrices2 = numpy.array_split(matrices, np)
    start = time()
    pool = Pool(processes=np)
    count = pool.map(counting, matrices2)
    stop = time()

    print("Parallel Calculation took ", stop - start, 'seconds')
```

The compiler displays the following errors:

File "/.../Matrix1.py", line 45, in 
    counting(matrices)
  File "/.../Matrix1.py", line 21, in counting
    left_matrix = matrix_multiplication(left_matrix, matrix)
  File "/.../Matrix1.py", line 12, in matrix_multiplication
    return (A * B)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 343, in **mul**
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: shapes (6,6) and (5,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)
Please help, I would like this algorithm to work properly.

Comment: does the text look exactly like what you have provided in the comment with a heading called 'Matrix # 1[5x8] ? What about the second matrix. is it seperated by ----- ? what do you want it to look like finally ?

Comment: @Vipluv I have just written examples of the matrix into the post

Comment: is your single matrix  line spread over two rows or is it just an artifact of posting the text of the matrix here ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it does not work." You should also verify the exact format of the text files, as requested in previous comments. We would all benefit if you read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Vipluv Single Matrix is divided into two rows

Comment: @Vipluv a single line of the matrix is split into two rows if its size is greater than 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented before, I believe regex might be the best way to parse your text file.
The code below works in the input you gave

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
matrices = []
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('matrices-2-2.txt', 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
    # gets each matrix based on the pattern [[ ]]
    matrices_string = re.findall("\[([\d\s.\n\]\[]+)\]", content)
    #loops over each matrix
    for matrix_string in matrices_string:
        # parses each row of the matrix
        matrix_rows = re.findall("\[([\d\s.\n\]]+)\]", matrix_string)
        # gets all the numbers for each row of the matrix and remakes the matrix as a list of floats
        matrices.append([list(map(float, re.findall("\d+\.\d+", row))) for row in matrix_rows]) 
    pprint(current_matrix)
```

A piece of the output:

```
[[[0.0322202,
   0.09434484,
   0.25002295,
   0.2528428,
   0.10415784,
   0.24142196,
   0.010517,
   0.25487851],
  [0.18335361,
   0.1277445,
   0.06118253,
   0.18690019,
   0.20396079,
   0.28628478,
   0.23368012,
   0.07932863],
  [0.01586491,
```

To multiply the matrices you should load a matrix like this:
matrix_1 = numpy.array(my_matrix_as_list_1)
matrix_2 = numpy.array(my_matrix_as_list_2)
Then you can do the matrix multiplication like this:
result = numpy.dot(matrix_1, matrix_2)

Comment: Thanks Pedro Torres! I managed to load the matrices. However, I encounter a problem during their multiplication...I added the code in the problem description. I would ask for help...

Comment: I am glad it helped! I don't see multiplication error you mentioned

Comment: Could you give more details on how to correct the code? I care a lot about that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These conditions `row == "-------------------------"`, `row == "Matrix"` will never be truth, since each row is an array.

I can guess that you're getting a `ValueError` exception.

So, to fix your code, you'll need to compare the first row element as follows `line[0] == "matrix"` or `"-" in line[0]`

You also have brackets at your value lines, get rid of it.

Since you're not using a valid CSV file, I think you can change your code to just iterate over the file and when you found a value line you can use the `line.split(' ')` command, as the example below:

```
for line in open('matrix.txt', 'r'):
    if "matrix" in line or "-" in line:
        continue

    print([float(element) for element in line.split(' ')])
```